# Laravel migration uses different .env every time

Tags: php, laravel

Project has two enviroment files, .env.dev и .env.prod, db settings differ like `DB_HOST=mysql` and `DB_HOST=mysql-dev`

Now i'm getting different results every time running `php artisan migrate:status --env=production` - some migrations ran at dev but none at production.

This sounds like --env=production is not working at db settings are complete random every time.

tried clearing cache, config:cache

Comment: at development server everything works fine, no switching db's, except  --env=production does nothing - output from artisan migrate matches one with no env key specified

Comment: What version of Laravel do you use? Is there an `.env` file in your project folder?

Comment: laravel 5.7, .env.prod(dev) file is moved to .env at deployment

Answer (score 0):

Try to create `.env` file on your local machine (with local settings). Also, add it to `.gitignore` (that prevents conflicts with file on production server). Files like `.env.xxx` are not in use.

Comment: Take a look at my previous comment. Each server has its own env file alright